# How can i authenticate with *.WSQ file with my secugen scanner fingerprint result?

Tags: php, fingerprint, biometrics

I have a secugen hamster pro 20 Scanner, with their web api they return Template(base64), Image WSQ Size, EncodeWSQ(base64), NFIQ (1–5), Quality, BMPBase64, etc params. I have matched two fingerprint with those returned data from the scanner, but the issue is that I have lots of physically stored *.WSQ format biometric data file in my storage so my question is that how can I authenticate with *.WSQ file with my scanner fingerprint result?

Answer (score 2):

You have to perform an enrollment process.

Which means you need to map person (using his ID number for example) with his fingerprint WSQ file.

The simplest way could be to name the WSQ file with the person ID number.

At verification time, you need to retrieve the person WSQ file using his ID number, and match it with the fingerprint scanner result WSQ.